# Track multiple user location and display in Client App using Socket in android

Tags: php, android, sockets, websocket

1> I want to create an app which tracks Multiple user locations and send it to Server
2> Than send data to a Client device and its display Map on screen

This app is working like Uber and Ola.

> For send/receive location, I want to implement Socket connection So if
>   anyone has any solution please write on a comment or ping me answer.

**Driver1, Driver2, etc..** > **Back-End(All Drivers)** > **Client Device**

Comment: You are on wrong window.. Please make same question on freelancer. com.

Comment: Thank you for your precious suggestion